# Problema al subir proyecto en GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-push

Llevo 2 días intentando colgar en github un proyecto, pero después de intentarlo desde GitBash y Sourcetree, me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensando que podría ser tema de firewall, los he desactivado, y nada. He probado de subir el proyecto desde otro ordenador y tampoco ha podido ser. Realmente no entiendo qué significa este mensaje de error, y tampoco se como podría solucionarlo. Agradecería ayuda.

Comment: NO PONGAS CAPTURA DE PANTALLA, coloca el error en texto porfavor

Answer (score 2):

antes de nada imagino que tienes instalado git en tu computadora , suponiendo eso ve a la raiz de tu proyecto desde la terminal.

antes de nada Crea un nuevo repositorio en GitHub(si ya lo tienes okay). Para evitar errores, no inicialice el nuevo repositorio con los archivos README, license o gitignore. Puede agregar estos archivos después de que su proyecto haya sido enviado a GitHub.

Inicialice el directorio local como un repositorio de Git.

```
git init
```

Agregue los archivos en su nuevo repositorio local. Esto los prepara para el primer compromiso.

```
git add .
```

Agrega los archivos en el repositorio local y los etapas para la confirmación. Para dejar de grabar un archivo, use 'git reset HEAD YOUR-FILE'.

Confirma los archivos que has organizado en tu repositorio local(tu proyecto)

```
git commit -m "Primer commit"
```

Confirma los cambios rastreados y los prepara para enviarlos a un repositorio remoto. Para eliminar este compromiso y modificar el archivo, use 'git reset --soft HEAD ~ 1' y confirme y agregue el archivo nuevamente.

En la parte superior de la página Configuración rápida del repositorio de GitHub, haga clic para copiar la URL del repositorio remoto.

```
git remote add origin remote repository URL
# Establece el nuevo control remoto
git remote -v
# Verifica la nueva URL remota
```

despues haces push a los cambios en su repositorio local a GitHub.

```
git push origin master
```

con el push se modifican los cambios en su repositorio local hasta el repositorio remoto que especificó como origen

[mas info](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)

un problema comun que pasa es que no has agregados los user de git para eso solamente mira este sencillo tutorial:
[usuarios - github](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)